# .NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, исключения, pendingintent

Привет всем. Пытался установить коммуникацию между MainActivity и Service при помощи PendingIntent. Делал это я, модифицировав пример, который находится [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/160-urok-95-service-obratnaja-svjaz-s-pomoschju-pendingintent.html).
Получилось нечто вот такое.

```
     @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     PendingIntent pi;
            Intent intent1;               
            pi = createPendingResult(1, null, 0);

            intent1 = new Intent(this, ServiceRun.class).putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);;
            startService(intent1);

        }

Получаю ошибку:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.raspisanierksi/com.example.admin.raspisanierksi.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3139)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3238)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6862)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.createPendingResult(Activity.java:5213)
                                                                                      at com.example.admin.raspisanierksi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:125)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6536)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3238) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6862) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Не могу понять, из-за чего она происходит, не загуглилось (.
MainActivity.java:125 это ссылка вот на эту строку:

```
pi = createPendingResult(1, null, 0);
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что к чему. Заранее спасибо.

PS
Подозреваю, что это связано cо вторым параметром в createPendingResult. AS не нравится, что там стоит null, но ошибки не выдает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации четко указано, This value **must never be null**. Интент передаваемый в конструктор, это тот, который будет хранить в себе создаваемый PendingIntent.
в таком виде

```
    PendingIntent piRequest;
    Intent ServiceIntent = new Intent();
    piRequest = createPendingResult(1, ServiceIntent, 0);
    ServiceIntent.putExtra("", piRequest);
```

работает.

[createPendingResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#createPendingResult(int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))